# TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Tags: python

Не получается список преобразовать в множества

```
col = int(input())
a, b = [], []
for i in range(col):
    a.append(input().split())
    print(i)
for i in range(col):
    b.append(input().split())

list3 = list(set(a) - set(b))

print(list3)
```

Comment: Предполагаю, что должно быть `a.extend(input().split())` и `b.extend(input().split())`

Comment: А в чем разница?

Comment: В том что append добавляет `input().split()` как вложенный список, а `extend` добавляет все элементы из `input().split()` как элементы списка a. Список можно преобразовать в set только если все его элементы хэшируемы. Список - не хэшируемый объект, поэтому нужно не как элемент добавлять, а "распаковать" его элементы в общий список.

Comment: Понял, спасибо!